# how do I throw error from interceptor to the caller function

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

in driver.ts file, I make an http call, like this

```
this.http.get(GetDrivers + '?service_identifier=' + 'road_logistic' + '&page=' + '1').subscribe((response:any) => {
      console.log("gio");
    }, err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I also have interceptor for all http calls. here it is.

```
 return observablePromise.pipe(mergeMap(user_tokens => {
            let access_token = user_tokens ? user_tokens.access_token : null;
            let clonedReq = this.addToken(request, access_token);

            return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
                tap( 
                    evt =>{
                        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            console.log("nice");
                            this.loaderService.storeLoaderOff();
                        }
                    },
                    error =>{
                      throwError("my error");
                    }
              )})
```

so the thing is, I make driver http call by hand as an error. it comes to tap's error handler in interceptor,( i know, because console.log shows up), but throwError doesn't work. what it should be doing is "my error" has to be thrown to the caller(driver.ts http call). as you see in driver http call, i catch errors and console log them. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your interceptor so it'll use **catchError** and generate your custom error:

```
return observablePromise.pipe(mergeMap(user_tokens => {
    let access_token = user_tokens ? user_tokens.access_token : null;
    let clonedReq = this.addToken(request, access_token);

    return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
        tap( 
            evt =>{
                if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log("nice");
                    this.loaderService.storeLoaderOff();
                }
            }
        ),
       catchError(error =>{          // <--- this part
              throwError("my error");
       })
    })
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do the error thing inside tap. 
Should look more like this:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('tap')),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return throwError('my error');
    }
);
```

Comment: even though I write this, inside my driver.ts file, when i console log error, it's httperrorresponse instead of "my error".